# mysql group results by days with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

i have payments table when someone buys item i add 1 record with amount and date

[image: payments table]

some buyers needs extra services with item (shipping-support ...)
so i have services table with price of service and payment_id

[image: Services Table]

i want results like this

```
   date    -  Sum(payments)  -  Sum(services)
01-01-2016 -    200          -       100
02-01-2016 -    200          -       100
03-01-2016 -    100          -        0
```

i have tried this query

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)),SUM(amount),SUM(price) 
FROM payments 
LEFT JOIN services ON payments.id = service.payment_id 
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))
```

but returns duplicated values
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subquery that joins the two tables and sums the prices for each payment. Then you can group that result by date.

```
SELECT date, SUM(payments), SUM(services)
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.date)) AS date, p.amount AS payments, IFNULL(SUM(s.price), 0) AS services
    FROM payments AS p
    LEFT JOIN services AS s ON p.id = s.payment_id
    GROUP BY p.id
) AS subquery
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: thanks for ur help but totalprice in your query returns NULL !!

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data, or replace your images with text so I can copy and paste it into a demo?

Comment: I saw the problem, I've changed the answer.

Comment: the prob was in version of mysql i tried code on mariadb but now is working well thank u so much